# Excel VBA : WorkSheet_FollowHyperlink is not getting called for Shape Object ( msoPicture )

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I need to have a macro executed when someone clicks on the shape in the worksheet which is a picture. The macro intention is to display more information regarding the shape on which the user clicked. 
EDIT: I also needed an information display during mouse-rollover, hence used hyperlink method.

I followed the method outlined in the [MSDN](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838843%28v=office.15%29.aspx&ei=bng-U7rdC4aIrQe9pYGQAw&usg=AFQjCNFj3kZGaBBQY8IgS5RnodUUchDB6A&bvm=bv.64125504,d.bmk) , but the macro just doesn't seem to run.

My Macro is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
  MsgBox "Source: Target.Range.Address  " & Target.Range.Address
  MsgBox "Source: Target.Range.Value " & Target.Range(1, 1).Value
  ' Some more macro stuff here
End Sub
```

- On clicking the picture I get to the sheet where the hyperlink target
  is, but the macro doesn't get executed.
- I created a dummy hyperlink on one of the cells (in the same sheet), if I click that one the macro is executed.
- I used the hyperlink method to have the rollover information on the picture shape.

I am totally out of ideas about how to go about this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated my answer as per your recent edit and your comment under my answer :)

Comment: Apparently I believe one cannot have roll-over from a hyperlink AND a macro linked to a shape  ( atleast I could not find one ).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that method. Use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` instead of `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink`.

So change your code to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    '~~> Change A1 to the cell which is behind the shape
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Visible = xlSheetVisible
            .Activate
        End With

        '
        '~~> Other Code if required
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

Next, Right Click on the Shape and click on `Hyperlink` and hyperlink to a cell behind the shape. You may also display information using the `ScreenTip` button in the `Insert hyperlink` dialog box.

We will do the sheet activating part in the above code rather than letting Excel do it.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, but I did not follow this route because I wanted to have the mouse-rollover, which is possible (only) when I have the HyperLink (from the Shape).

Comment: That is because `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` is an event for the worksheet and not for the Shape.