# Hyperlink not triggering macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get all hyperlinks with a specific target range to activate a routine. Although the hyperlinks themselves work fine (target address range ("A1") is selected when I click on the hyperlinks), my routine is not being triggered when I click on them.

The code below is in the "Sheet1" module of my workbook and the hyperlinks target range "A1" within the "Sheet1" worksheet. There are a total of 5 other sheets in the workbook.

I'm really stumped as to why the code is failing to trigger. Any help would be much appreciated!

- Checked the hyperlinks themselves were working and targeting a range on the same worksheet the routine is linked to.
- Removed the "call macro" part of the code and replaced it with a simple message box to check if the routine is being triggered at all.
- Tried placing the routine in the "ThisWorkbook" module instead - this also had no results.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$1" Then
        MsgBox ("Yay")
    End If
End Sub
```

The routine above should be triggered after clicking on the hyperlinks with a target range of "A1", meaning that the message box text should appear to the user.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether that handler should be in all 6 sheets, or whether it's only on `Sheet1`. In any case, grabbing any worksheet event handler and moving it into `ThisWorkbook` can't possibly work - the signature doesn't match, it's not a `Workbook` event.

Comment: I think it is: Target.Address

Comment: How is the hyperlink created? What does `Debug.Print Sheet1.Hyperlinks.Count` return?

Comment: @Guest `Target` is a `Hyperlink`, not a `Range`. The `Address` of a hyperlink pointing to e.g. `stackoverflow.com` would be `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @Mathieu, yes you are right! My mistake sorry. But here is an interesting link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858643/excel-vba-worksheet-followhyperlink-is-not-getting-called-for-shape-object-m

Comment: There are different ways of creating clickable hyperlinks, but not all of them create a `Hyperlink` object in the worksheet's `Hyperlinks` collection. Without knowing how the hyperlnks are created, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SubAddress vs Sheet1!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
```

> ```
>     If Target.Range.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress = "Sheet1!A1" Then
> ```

```
        MsgBox ("Yay")
    End If
End Sub
```